# How do I convert a text file to a list in python?

Tags: python, list, file, text

My current text file looks like:

```
1DEC     S1    1   2.192   2.811   1.924
2DEC     S1    4   3.686   3.143   3.151
3DEC     S1    7   3.622   2.211   3.252
4DEC     S1   10   3.697   3.401   2.558
5DEC     S1   13   1.921   2.136   2.711
```

etc.

I'd like to convert it into a list with only the last 3 numbers in each line, like:

```
[2.192, 2.811, 1.924, 3.686, 3.143, 3.151, 3.622, 2.211, 3.252, 3.697, 3.401 2.558, 1.921, 2.136, 2.711]
```

Thank you!

Comment: post your current code

Comment: I'm very new python so I haven't really been able to make any progress. I figured this question would be too specific to get answered.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy has a easy way of doing this.

```
import numpy as np
a,b = np.loadtxt('FILE LOCATION',usecols=('Column Number with 0 being 
first', unpack=True)
```

In this case a and b should give you your list for the columns respectively.
For example if you want to use to 4th or 5th column you can say usecols=(5,6) etc and so forth.  Since you do not need the column with the strings no additional steps would be necessary.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "could not convert string to float: b'1DEC' "

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner using `list-comprehension`:

```
with open('test.txt.', 'r') as f:
    print [float(x) for line in f for x in line.split()[3:]]
```

output:

```
[2.192, 2.811, 1.924, 3.686, 3.143, 3.151, 3.622, 2.211, 3.252, 3.697, 3.401, 2.558, 1.921, 2.136, 2.711]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain

f = open('filename.txt').readlines()

f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in f]

new_vals = list(chain(*[map(float, i[3:]) for i in f]))
```

Output:

```
[2.192, 2.811, 1.924, 3.686, 3.143, 3.151, 3.622, 2.211, 3.252, 3.697, 3.401, 2.558, 1.921, 2.136, 2.711]
```